# I can't connect to my hot spot？

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I can turn on my Laptop computer hot spot，As shown in figure：

[image]

But when my phone tries to connect to computer hot spot, it shuts down.
configuration：arch,gnome3.36

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are doing. Are you using a mobile phone as a hotspot? Are you using your Arch machine as a hotspot? What is trying to connect to what?

Answer (score -1):

```
dnsmasq
sudo pacman -S dnsmasq
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind adding some explanation on _why_ you think this solves the OPs problem and _how_ you concluded what the problem was?